# Efficiently count occurrences of a value with groupby and within a date range

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, vectorization

I have code that can do this, but I am iterating through each row of the dataframe with `iterrows()`. It takes quite a long time to process considering it's checking through over 6M rows. And want to use vectorisation to speed it up.

I've looked at using `pd.Grouper` and `freq`, but have gotten stuck on how to use the 2 dataframes to do this check with that.

Given the 2 dataframes below:

I want to look at all rows in `df1` (grouped by `'sid'` and `'modtype'`):

**df1:**

```
   sid servid       date modtype service
0  123    881 2022-07-05      A1       z
1  456    879 2022-07-02      A2       z
```

Then find them in `df2` and count the occurrences of those groups within 3 days of the date of that group in `df1`, to get a count of how many times that group comes within 3 days before, and a count of occurrences it comes within 3 days after.

**df2:**

```
    sid servid       date modtype
0   123   1234 2022-07-03      A1
1   123    881 2022-07-05      A1
2   123  65781 2022-07-06      A1
3   123   8552 2022-07-30      A1
4   123   3453 2022-07-04      A2
5   123   5681 2022-07-07      A2
6   456     78 2022-07-01      A1
7   456  26744 2022-05-05      A2
8   456  56166 2022-06-29      A2
9   456  56717 2022-06-30      A2
10  456    879 2022-07-02      A2
11  456     56 2022-07-25      A2
```

So, essentially, in the sample set which I provide below, my output would end up with:

```
   sid servid       date modtype service  cnt_3day_before   cnt_3day_after
0  123    881 2022-07-05      A1       z    1                 1
1  456    879 2022-07-02      A2       z    2                 0
```

**Sample set:**

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'sid':['123','456'],
    'servid':['881','879'],
    'date':['2022-07-05','2022-07-02'],
    'modtype':['A1','A2'],
    'service':['z','z']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['sid','modtype','date'], ascending=[True, True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)



data2 = {
        'sid':['123','123','123','123','123','123',
               '456','456','456','456','456','456'],
        'servid':['1234','3453','881','65781','5681','8552',
                  '26744','56717','879','56166','56','78'],
        'date':['2022-07-03','2022-07-04','2022-07-05','2022-07-06','2022-07-07','2022-07-30',
                '2022-05-05','2022-06-30','2022-07-02','2022-06-29','2022-07-25','2022-07-01'],
        'modtype':['A1','A2','A1','A1','A2','A1',
                   'A2','A2','A2','A2','A2','A1']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['sid','modtype','date'], ascending=[True, True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I would merge the datasets first then do the group by counts.

Comment: Do you have rows in `df1` already grouped? If not, then how do you define date for the group of rows in `df1`?

Comment: In your solution, do you iterate through `df1` or `df2`? There is a simple solution that iterates through `df1`. Which dataframe is the big one `df1` or `df2`?

Comment: I iterate through df1. And the huge one is df2 (over 6M rows). It’s just taking a bit to long of a time to do it row by row. So was thinking if I could somehow vectorise it to do it working groupby.

Comment: And no I wasn’t doing a groupby. I basically look at the first row, grab the sid, date, modtype (and get the date 3days before the 3 days after). Then go into df2 and filter/query by that sid, modtype, count how many rows are 3 days before, then count down for 3 days after. Then move on to the next row  in df1 and do the same. I mean it works, but just feel there is always a better way to do it than using iterrows.

Comment: @chitown88 I think count_3day_before for (456, A2) should be 1

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I’ll double check that. Was doing this on the fly. But I’m pretty sure there’s 2 rows within the 3day window there.

Comment: @chitown88 No worries. I think you want to consider boundaries excluding the current value...In that case 2 is correct.

Comment: Ya I know what you mean. This was just an example. I can also rework the small stuff. Just trying to figure out the main processing part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Annotated code

```
# Merge the dataframes on sid and modtype
keys = ['sid', 'modtype']
s = df2.merge(df1[[*keys, 'date']], on=keys, suffixes=['', '_'])

# Create boolean condtitions as per requirements
s['cnt_3day_after']  = s['date'].between(s['date_'], s['date_'] + pd.DateOffset(days=3), inclusive='right')
s['cnt_3day_before'] = s['date'].between(s['date_'] - pd.DateOffset(days=3), s['date_'], inclusive='left' )

# group the boolean conditions by sid and modtype
# and aggregate with sum to count the number of True values
s = s.groupby(keys)[['cnt_3day_after', 'cnt_3day_before']].sum()

# Join the aggregated counts back with df1
df_out = df1.join(s, on=keys)
```

#### Result

```
print(df_out)

   sid servid       date modtype service  cnt_3day_after  cnt_3day_before
0  123    881 2022-07-05      A1       z               1                1
1  456    879 2022-07-02      A2       z               0                2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are definitely exist faster solutions, but you can try this one. It iterates over "queries" in `df1` and for each `query` computes number of events in `df2` that happened before and after 3 days. To calculate number of such events we first set `sid` and `modtype` to be an index column, then we select matching events by index and calculate time difference between the selected events and query, then we just count ones that happened in +/- 3 days. This place can be optimized with binary search to give you O(logN) instead of O(N) complexity in case you have sorted date column.

```py
df2 = df2.set_index(['sid', 'modtype'])
seconds_in_3days = 3*24*60*60
    
def before_and_after_3days(query):
    dates = df2.loc[tuple(query[['sid', 'modtype']]), 'date']
    secs = (dates - query['date']).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
    before = ((-seconds_in_3days <= secs) & (secs < 0)).sum()
    after = ((0 < secs) & (secs < seconds_in_3days)).sum()
    return before, after
    
before_after = df1.apply(before_and_after_3days, axis=1)
df1[['cnt_3day_before', 'cnt_3day_after']] = before_after.tolist()
```

Comment: Ya this is more or less how I’m already doing it. Just trying to figure it out for something that doesn’t process it in a row by row way but rather vecorized

Answer (score 1):

Use a `groupby` to allow a processing function to gain access to each unique `sid` and `modtype` sub-frame.  In that function do some date arithmetic to build and sum boolean maps to get counts of the applicable days before and after. Then merge back into the original target filtering frame (`df1`).

**Processing Function**

```
def a(x):
    s = x['sid_y'].isna()
    
    if s.all():
        rc = [0,0]
    else:
        bdate = x.at[(~s).idxmax(),'date']
        td = pd.Timedelta('3D')

        nb_before = ((bdate > x['date']) & (bdate - x['date'] <= td)).sum()
        nb_after = ((bdate < x['date']) & (x['date'] - bdate < td)).sum()
   
        rc = [nb_before,nb_after]
    
    return pd.Series(rc, index=['3before','3after'])
```

**Execution**

```
mk = ['sid','modtype'] 

dfc = df1.merge(df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='date', suffixes=['', '_y'])
       .groupby(mk).apply(a).reset_index(), on=mk)

print(dfc)
```

**Result**

```
   sid servid       date modtype service  3before  3after
0  123    881 2022-07-05      A1       z        1       1
1  456    879 2022-07-02      A2       z        2       0
```

Comment: Thanks. Ya no rush, won’t get back to this tomorrow. Ya I’m not worried about the renaming and that stuff